# Find a reduction formula for the following:

Tags: calculus, integration, reduction-of-order-ode

$$I_n = \int\frac{x^{2n}}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$

Having difficulty with, 
$$x^{2n}$$
oppose to the more common, 
$$x^{n}$$
which can be split into:
$$x^{n-1}*x$$
Used integration by parts to achieve the following by letting: 
$$u = x^{2n-1}$$ 
$$du = \frac{x^{2n-2}dx}{2n-2}$$
$$dv = \frac{xdx}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$
$$v = {(x^2+1)^{1/2}}$$
Then started algebra to achieve the following:
$$I_n = {x^{2n-1}}{(x^2+1)}^{1/2} - \int\frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}(x)^{2n-2}dx}{(2n-2)}$$
I know that, 
$$I_n = \int\frac{x^{2n}}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$
Just wondering if,
$$\int\frac{(x^2+1)^{1/2}(x)^{2n-2}dx}{(2n-2)} = I_{n-2}$$
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite:
$$\int(x^2+1)^{1/2}x^{2n-2}\,dx=\int\frac{(x^2+1) \,x^{2n-2}}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}\,dx=\int\frac{x^{2n}+x^{2n-2}}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}\,dx=I_{n}+I_{n-1}$$
 Then, taking into account the factor of $\frac1{2n-2}$, you'd get something like $$\frac{2n-1}{2n-2} I_n=x^{2n-1}(x^2+1)^{1/2}-\frac{I_{n-1}}{2n-2}$$